# What’s the most compression that we can hope for a file that contains 1000 bits (Huffman algorithm)?

Tags: algorithm, theory, huffman-code

How much file that contains 1000 bits, where 1 appears with a 10% probability of 0 - 90% probability can be compressed with Huffman code?

Comment: A bound is provided by Shannon capacity

Comment: What in the world does "10% probability of 0 - 90% probability" mean?

Comment: How are you applying Huffman compression? If there are just two symbols (0 and 1) naive Huffman won't compress anything. If you start treating blocks of bits as individual characters, you may be able to improve things a bit.

Comment: see [Compute Shannon information entropy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64785375/2521214) the result will tell you exactly what is the avg bit depth for any word in yoru data set from which you can compute the compression ratio as you got the probabilities ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a factor of two.

But only if you do not include the overhead of sending the description of the Huffman code along with the data. For 1000 bits, that overhead will dominate the problem, and determine your maximum compression ratio. I find that for that small of a sample, 125 bytes, general-purpose compressors get it down to only around 100 to 120 bytes, due to the overhead.

A custom Huffman code just for this on bytes from such a stream gives a factor of 2.10, assuming the other side already knows the code. The best you could hope for is the entropy, e.g. with an arithmetic code, which gives 2.13.